# how to maintain focus of edittext while working with multiple edittexts?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using six edittexts in OTP screeen to retrieve OTP from user. Using setOnKeyListener method to detect delete/backspace key event to put focus to previous edittext to allow user to remove digits entered.

```
et6.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK | keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                et5.setSelected(true);
                et5.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Now issue is focus jumps to the edittext 4 instead of editext 5. How to resolve this issue? Please provide your suggestions to fix the issue it would be helpful.

Comment: You can define properties android:nextFocusDown="@id/editText" in every editText Field this way it will be a proper sequence of events. Starting with the first editText you define android:nextFocusDown="@id/editText2" then for the second android:nextFocusDown="@id/editText3" and so on. Also dont forget to add android:nextFocusUp="@id/editText" for editTexts 2 to 6 and android:nextFocusDown="@id/editText" for editTexts 1 to 5 only. Hope it helps you

Comment: Sure do let me know in case this doesn't work

Comment: @Hascher No it didn't work. I tried setting focusUp for edittext 2 to 6 and focusDown to edittext 1 to 5. For focusDown I gave id of next edittext and for focusUp I gave id of previous edittext. I hope it was correct. Please let me know if there is any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case, this might help you. I am using OTP handling like this:

```
    private fun enterOtp() {

        val editTexts: Array<EditText> = arrayOf(etOtp1, etOtp2, etOtp3, etOtp4)

        etOtp1.addTextChangedListener(
            PinTextWatcher(
                0,
                editTexts,
                otpMandatoryTV,
                this
            )
        )
        etOtp2.addTextChangedListener(
            PinTextWatcher(
                1,
                editTexts,
                otpMandatoryTV,
                this
            )
        )
        etOtp3.addTextChangedListener(
            PinTextWatcher(
                2,
                editTexts,
                otpMandatoryTV,
                this
            )
        )
        etOtp4.addTextChangedListener(
            PinTextWatcher(
                3,
                editTexts,
                otpMandatoryTV,
                this
            )
        )

        etOtp1.setOnKeyListener(PinOnKeyListener(0, editTexts))
        etOtp2.setOnKeyListener(PinOnKeyListener(1, editTexts))
        etOtp3.setOnKeyListener(PinOnKeyListener(2, editTexts))
        etOtp4.setOnKeyListener(PinOnKeyListener(3, editTexts))
   }
```

And this is the class:

```
class PinTextWatcher internal constructor(
    private val currentIndex: Int,
    private val editTexts: Array<EditText>,
    private val mandatoryText: TextView,
    private val activity: Activity) : TextWatcher {


    private var isFirst = false
    private var isLast = false
    private var newTypedString = ""
    override fun beforeTextChanged(
        s: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        count: Int,
        after: Int
    ) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(
        s: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        before: Int,
        count: Int
    ) {
        newTypedString = s.subSequence(start, start + count).toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        var text = newTypedString

        /* Detect paste event and set first char */if (text.length > 1) text =
            text[0].toString() // TODO: We can fill out other EditTexts
        editTexts.get(currentIndex).removeTextChangedListener(this)
        editTexts.get(currentIndex).setText(text)
        editTexts.get(currentIndex).setSelection(text.length)
        editTexts.get(currentIndex).addTextChangedListener(this)
        if (text.length == 1) moveToNext() else if (text.length == 0) moveToPrevious()
        mandatoryText.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    private fun moveToNext() {
        if (!isLast) editTexts.get(currentIndex + 1).requestFocus()
        if (isAllEditTextsFilled && isLast) { // isLast is optional
            editTexts.get(currentIndex).clearFocus()
            hideKeyboard()
        }
    }

    private fun moveToPrevious() {
        if (!isFirst) editTexts.get(currentIndex - 1).requestFocus()
    }

    private val isAllEditTextsFilled: Boolean
        private get() {
            for (editText in editTexts) if (editText.text.toString()
                    .trim { it <= ' ' }.length == 0
            ) return false
            return true
        }

    private fun hideKeyboard() {
        if (activity.currentFocus != null) {
            val inputMethodManager =
                activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            val view = activity.currentFocus
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view?.getWindowToken(), 0)
        }
    }

    init {
        if (currentIndex == 0) isFirst =
            true else if (currentIndex == editTexts.size - 1) isLast = true
    }
}

class PinOnKeyListener internal constructor(
    private val currentIndex: Int,
    private val editTexts: Array<EditText>) : View.OnKeyListener {


    override fun onKey(
        v: View,
        keyCode: Int,
        event: KeyEvent
    ): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (editTexts.get(currentIndex).getText().toString()
                    .isEmpty() && currentIndex != 0
            ) editTexts.get(currentIndex - 1).requestFocus()
        }
        return false
    }
```

}

This code is Kotlin and its working. You can convert to Java. If you are not able to let me know I will help along. Also adjust the handling according to your need. I have used 4 fields for OTP. In your case it will be six.

Comment: Thank you for help. It would be really helpful if you could share this code in java.

Comment: where can I concat the String in above code to form an OTP?

Comment: You can concat the string in the if check that is if (isAllEditTextsFilled && isLast) { editTexts[0].text.toString() + editTexts[1].text.toString() + editTexts[2].text.toString() + editTexts[3].text.toString() + editTexts[4].text.toString() + editTexts[5].text.toString() }

Comment: You still need the Java code? Or you did it?

Comment: Yes I did it. Thank you for asking.

Comment: That's good to know :)